# How to extract mili second from zulu timing using regex

Tags: regex

I have below time format and i want only the mentioned format except the mili second:

```
Input Format : 2012-11-08T20:50:56.073Z
Expected Format : 2012-11-08 20:50:56
```

Please help as i am new to regex. What i m trying to do is removing first T and Z from the time and then extracting timestamp but it is not working.

How can I extract year from date for below mentioned formats ?

```
example : input : 2012-11-08 20:50:56 or 2012-11-08 
Output: 2012
```

Comment: *"...but it is not working".* What is?

Comment: Please convert thisinto a question and also show the regex you have created so far to try and get it to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this regex to get to expected format,

```
^(\d{4}(?:\-\d{2}){2})T((?:\d{2}:){2}\d{2}).*$
```

Match this regex and then capture group 1 and group 2 separated by a space like \1 \2

Let me know if you need any explanation.

Demo,

https://regex101.com/r/Ik0e8F/1

Comment: Pleased to help :)